# What 3d file format should I use to import low poly shapes?

Tags: import, file-format

I'm a metal artist and think I can learn blender enough so I can create my sculpture ideas, render them and submit them to sculpture jobs.

Hoping I can shave off some time by importing 3d files that I can then modify and shape to fulfill my design ideas.

What 3d file should I be looking for if it's possible to import?
Will an .obj file work?

Comment: If you click on File button (top header menu bar) > Import, you'll see all the kind of formats you can import

Comment: I guess with just a low-poly mesh, no texture, materials etc. an .obj file should work well. Maybe .3ds as well.

Comment: I gave this question a downvote, because it shows no research effort at all.

Answer (score 0):

Blender offers a wide range of popular file formats (e.g. OBJ, FBX, 3DS, PLY, STL, etc.) that can be used to import and export.  Please note that many of the import/export features are enabled by the use of addons.  See the [import/export addons](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/addons/import_export/index.html#addons-io) section of the manual for details.